# Communication failure with jdbc in java

Tags: java, mysql, database, jdbc

I'm trying to make a connection to a mysql database that we are hosting. We have installed phpmyadmin on it and we can easily access the database and it's content from there. (http://ipadress:port/phpmyadmin)

The problem is that we keep getting communication failure. This is the piece of Java code I have:

```
public static void main(String[] args) {
    Connection conn;
    Statement st;
    ResultSet rs;
    try {
        Class.forName("com.mysql.jdbc.Driver");
        conn = DriverManager.getConnection("jdbc:mysql://ipadress/Database", "user", "password");
        st = conn.createStatement();

        String query = "SELECT * FROM adres";
        assert st != null;
        rs = st.executeQuery(query);
        System.out.println("Records from Database");
        while (rs.next()) {
            String straat = rs.getString("straat");
            String huisnummer = rs.getString("huisnummer");
            System.out.println("Straat: " + straat + "\nHuisnummer: " + huisnummer);
        }
    } catch (Exception ex) {
        System.out.println(ex.getMessage());
    }
}
```

I've also tried adding it to the mysql workbench but I keep getting the same error, so I'm guessing it's not code-wise. What could be the reason behind this? Since I have no problem connecting to it with the phpmyadmin.

Thanks!

EDIT:
The error message

```
Communications link failure
The last packet sent successfully to the server was 0 milliseconds ago. The driver has not received any packets from the server.
```

Comment: Paste the error you are getting in the question. That will give better idea about why you are not able to connect.

Comment: @AniketThakur Sorry I've added it

Comment: Can you connect to it with mysql from the client machine? Hint: My guess is no.

Comment: Have you started the mysql server?

Comment: First thing to do is ping the database server and see if it is reachable. Also see no firewall is blocking your connection or port.

Comment: @ElliottFrisch problem is that the client machine is from school and we don't have the rights to install anything

Comment: @Mnemonics Yes it's running

Comment: @user3142255 can you please show what ex.getCause() returns? So instead of System.out.println(ex.getMessage()) call ex.getCause()